# Is it possible to configure an IPv6 multicast address to a NIC?

Tags: linux-networking, ipv6, multicast

Is it possible to configure an address from `ff00::/8` address block to a NIC? Looks like it is not possible:

```
# ip a add ff99::1/8 dev p2p1
RTNETLINK answers: Cannot assign requested address
# 
# ip maddr add ff99::1/8 dev p2p1
"ff99" is invalid lladdr.
Error: "ff99" is not a legal ll address.
#
```

Comment: IPv6 multicast doesn't work that way. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: http://ipv6friday.org/blog/2011/12/ipv6-multicast/

Comment: `ff99::1` is not even a real IPv6 multicast address. The scope (`9`) in that address is unassigned, and a reserved flag is set.

Comment: `ip maddress add` only understands IPv4 multicast addresses anyway, from a quick look at the [source code](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/iproute2/iproute2.git/tree/ip/ipmaddr.c).